# SQL Server : loop through every row, add incremented value to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have just added a new column, `Person_Id_Helper` to `MyTable`. It is supposed to contain 1,2,3 etc, in the order the table is now sorted.

This is what I want to do:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @NumberOfRows INT = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable 

WHILE(@i <= @NumberOfRows)
BEGIN
   -- Person_Id_Helper = @i
   -- @i = @i + 1       
END
```

How do I write this?

Comment: @PeterSmith NO! dynamic SQL is **mostly** bad and CURSORs are **very** bad. Dynamic SQL is needed with dynamic PIVOT or in performance related special situations. There are **very** rare things you really need a cursor to solve it...

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer. I've deleted my comment! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve -

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
UPDATE MyTable
SET 
   @i = Person_Id_Helper = @i + 1
```

Now check your column value.

Well we can not use `ORDER BY` clause in update statement. But to use it here is the updated query.

```
UPDATE t
SET Person_Id_Helper = rn.RowNum
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT
        ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable) rn
    ON t.ID = rn.ID
```

@shungo: Thanks for point out.

Comment: Without a sorting this will be random... There is **absolutely no implicit sort order**

Comment: Actually, this worked exactly as I wanted! Very understandable to a newbie as well. Will accept as answer when I can. Thanks!

Comment: @hellogoodnight, it is on you - of course! - to decide which is best for you. But be aware that - from a technical point of view - this solution is awful. You cannot rely on any sort order your table seem to have at the moment...

Comment: @Shnugo I don´t understand the problem with this, but I will try to read your solution more thorough to understand. At least, this solution solved the problem I had. I gave you an upvote for helping me :)

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks for point out. I have edited my answer. You are right as  we can't rely on any sort order.

Comment: @hellogoodnight, If you query with `SELECT * FROM MyTable` you get a resultset which comes with some kind of sorting. If you insert your data in a sorted order, the resultset will (probably) look sorted as you inserted it. **But:** This sort order is not reliable. The next call might come back with a different order. Therefore this solution is not reliable, if you want to give a running number to persist some sort order.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, Yes, ROW_NUMBER() is suitable to guarantee a sorted resultset, as long as the ORDER BY is pointing to unique data...

Answer (score 4):

I think, that it might be the wrong idea to persist the sort oder within a column. But - for sure! - it is the wrong idea to do this in a while loop.

Read about row-based and set-based approaches. SQL demands for set-based thinking...

Look at this as an example how to do this (just paste it into an empty query window and execute, adapt to your needs):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SortDate DATE, Inx INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES({d'2016-01-20'},0)
                      ,({d'2016-01-19'},0)
                      ,({d'2016-01-14'},0)
                      ,({d'2016-01-16'},0);
WITH cte AS
(
       SELECT Inx,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortDate) AS RN
       FROM @tbl
)
UPDATE cte SET Inx=RN;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
  (
     datecolumn DATE,
     Person_Id_Helper  INT
  );

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES     ({d'2016-01-20'},
            0),
            ({d'2016-01-19'},
             0),
            ({d'2016-01-14'},
             0),
            ({d'2016-01-16'},
             0);

SELECT *
FROM   @tbl;

UPDATE T
SET    Person_Id_Helper = rn
FROM   (SELECT Person_Id_Helper,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY datecolumn) AS rn
        FROM   @tbl) T

SELECT *
FROM   @tbl;
```

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks for providing the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Looping add increment the value using cursor in sqlserver

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [PID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductDesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode], [Person_Id_Helper]) VALUES (1, N'Packet-Eye', N'P001', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode], [Person_Id_Helper]) VALUES (2, N'Wiggy', N'W099 ', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode], [Person_Id_Helper]) VALUES (3, N'Wimax-Lite', N'W001', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode], [Person_Id_Helper]) VALUES (4, N'Wimax-Home', N'e W002 ', NULL)
GO

Declare @count int
DECLARE @PID int 
set @count=0
DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT [PID] FROM [Table1] 
OPEN c1 
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @PID 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
set @count=@count+1
update Table1 set Person_Id_Helper=@count where [PID]=@PID
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @PID END 
CLOSE c1 
DEALLOCATE c1

select * from Table1
```

Comment: Please read through other answers and comments on this question! You are cummulating all bad habits and errors one could do... You rely on a given sort order which does not exist and you show procedural /row-based thinking by using a CURSOR / WHILE loop.